# ORA-24344: success with compilation error when trying to implement holt winter procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm getting the `ORA-24344: success with compilation` error whenever i try to import an application(that works on my database) to the oracle apex cloud or any other local cloud, the same error appears `ORA-24344: success with compilation` but when i run the application it runs but this procedure (holt_winters) does not run, no errors it just doesn't do anything.

[image]

here is my code. its a holt winters prediction method for those of you who're interested.
any help would be apperciated

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "HOLT_WINTERS" (report_id_in IN INTEGER
                             , alpha IN VARCHAR2
                             , beta IN VARCHAR2
                             , gamma IN VARCHAR2
                             , prediction_step IN VARCHAR2
                             , seasonality IN VARCHAR2
                             , from_date IN varchar2
                             , to_date IN varchar2
                             , FDEW_ID IN integer) AS
BEGIN
    begin
        -- delete previous settings
        delete from demo_ts_settings where report_id_in > 0;
        -- select ESM as the algorithm
        insert into demo_ts_settings
        values (dbms_data_mining.algo_name,
                dbms_data_mining.algo_exponential_smoothing);
        -- set ESM model to be Holt-Winters Seasonal Adjusted
        insert into demo_ts_settings
        values (dbms_data_mining.exsm_model,
                dbms_data_mining.exsm_HW_ADDSEA);
        -- set interval to be month
        insert into demo_ts_settings
        values (dbms_data_mining.exsm_interval,
                dbms_data_mining.exsm_interval_month);
        -- set prediction to 4 steps ahead
        insert into demo_ts_settings
        values (dbms_data_mining.exsm_prediction_step,
                prediction_step);
        -- set seasonal cycle to be 5 quarters
        insert into demo_ts_settings
        values (dbms_data_mining.exsm_seasonality,
                seasonality);
        BEGIN
            dbms_data_mining.drop_model('DEMO_TS_MODEL_' || report_id_in);
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN others THEN null;
        END;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create view holt_winters_temp_table_'||report_id_in|| ' as select RATES.*
        from RATES
        where (DATE_OF_RECORD between to_date('''|| from_date ||''', ''YYYY-MM-DD'') ' ||
                          'and to_date('''||to_date||''', ''YYYY-MM-DD'') )
          and STATUS = ''FALSE''
          and report_id ='|| report_id_in;
        dbms_data_mining.create_model(model_name => 'DEMO_TS_MODEL_' || report_id_in,
                                      mining_function => 'TIME_SERIES',
                                      data_table_name => 'holt_winters_temp_table_' || report_id_in,
                                      case_id_column_name => 'date_of_record',
                                      target_column_name => 'VAL',
                                      settings_table_name => 'DEMO_TS_SETTINGS');
        BEGIN
            FOR i IN 1..5
                LOOP
                    BEGIN
                        sys.DBMS_SESSION.sleep(20);
                        INSERT_HOLT_HISTORY('DM$PPDEMO_TS_MODEL_' || report_id_in);
                        COMMIT;
                        EXIT;
                    EXCEPTION
                        WHEN others THEN null;
                       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (SQLCODE || ' ' ||  SQLERRM);
                    END; -- sub-block ends
                END LOOP;
        END;
    end;
END HOLT_WINTERS;
```

Comment: Can you query the `user_errors` table to see the actual compilation error or try to compile the procedure and show us the error stack?  My guess is that the user in whose schema you're trying to create the procedure doesn't have access either to the `dbms_data_mining` package or to the `dbms_session` package (I'd guess the latter).

Comment: when i use the query user_errors it tells me no data found, and when i save and compile the procedure it gives me no errors, which is why this is driving me crazy